# How to render a Drupal 7 menu structure with divs instead of lists

Tags: theming, navigation

I want to change the output of the Drupal 7 menu structure which is like:

```
<?php print render($primary_nav); ?>
```

outputs:

```
<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="first expanded">
    <a title="" href="lorem">Lorem</a>
    <ul class="menu nav">
      <li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="/lorem">Lorem</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/ipsum">Ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/dolor">Dolor</a></li>
  <li class="expanded"><a title="" href="/sit">Sit</a>
    <ul class="menu nav">
      <li class="first leaf"><a title="" href="/sit">Amet</a></li>
      <li class="leaf"><a title="" href="/consectetur">Consectetur</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

how could I have instead of the `ul` and `li` the menu rendered with a `div` structure.

Comment: The question is why? The web, your users, etc expect this structure!

Comment: @AlexGill thanks but I need it in a certain way. I know about convention but I need to hook in classes and change the structure a bit.

Comment: Yeah...don't break semantics, especially the easy ones. There's no valid reason to do this from a technical point of view, lists of data should be in list elements. _However_: Find out where `$primary_nav` is being created (that's not a standard Drupal var, probably something in a custom/contrib theme). It'll likely be run through a theme function; your job is to override that theme function :)

Comment: @Clive I already have searched for it and don't know where exactly this is created.

Comment: Its created in the bootstrap module under theme/system/page.vars.php but all this is doing is assigning a rendered 'main menu'. As clive says the way to do this is through the theme function.

Comment: Only you can see your code @supersize, not possible (or useful to the knowledge repository) for us to guess what it looks like. Grep for `primary_nav`, you can't fail to find it

Comment: Agreed you would normally just handle this with styles. If all you want is a "div" structure, you can easily style the list elments to behave as divs... However I've had to hook into this at the theme level with hook_menu_link_alter... That does not let you alter the structure though. The only way to manipulate the construction of the menu is unfortunately by string manipulation (no handy hooks), so it is to be avoided at all costs.